# How about a Sandbox for drafts of long, complex posts like Math.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm referring to the following post in meta.Math.SE where ALL of the answers are [community wiki's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) which are used by people working on (long) questions or answers that are "in the works", need further research and editing prior to posting on the main site. The rules over there on Math are pretty straightforward, pick a "free for anyone to use" answer, use it, and release it back to the free pool by "clearing it" after you are done. The only drawback is, it will constantly show up on the front page due to numerous edits, but over time, people will get used to it and ignore it.

[meta.math.stackexchange.com/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666)

So, how about a Sandbox for Hinduism.SE on meta?

I can certainly see myself using it if it's there.

Of all users, I predict [this user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/36/keshav-srinivasan) will benefit most from this, also we all get a sneak peek of what's in the works from him ;-)

Comment: It's an interesting idea, and it would certainly help me as I frequently write long posts and I often encounter browser crashes and page refreshes that make me lose my work.  But I noticed [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts#comment86650_4666) in that Sandbox thread, suggesting that the website StackEdit serves this purpose even better.  But if you think having a Sandbox thread has advantages over StackEdit, I'm happy to hear your reasoning.

Comment: If you want a preview of my future posts, I actually have a long list of questions I'm planning to ask, and the list is constantly getting longer, and then every once in a while I take one of the questions on the list, do research to try to answer it, and then post it on the site.  I can show you the list in chat.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Oh, didn't know about stackedit.io, but looks like a paid product $5/yr and $25 lifetime if you want to save your documents under a login and access later. [Here](http://alternativeto.net/software/stackedit/) are the alternatives to StackEdit. One small drawback with these other software is you can't upload images while working on a post. So I think people will still benefit from having Hinduism.SE's own Sandbox.

Comment: I just wrote this question using Stackedit: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10296/36 (I intentionally chose to post a question that would involve lots of links and quotes.) It worked well, and you can save your documents and open your documents with Google Drive, so you don't need to pay 5 dollars.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Good you figured out how to save to Google drive.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that StackEdit turned out to be pretty much useless.  I wrote my last four or five posts using it, and it created a false sense of security with the save to Google Drive and Autosync with Google Drive buttons.  Then today I just wrote another question and my browser crashed, and when I tried to retrieve it I found out that none of my posts had actually been saved to Google Drive!  So I just lost a really long question I was about to post.  So I think I'll look into creating a Sandbox and/or the StackEdit alternatives you mentioned.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Oh sorry to hear that! One post I was working on StackEdit that looks fine and saved on Google drive. Maybe if you bought the paid version, it's more crash proof.

Comment: I would certainly this feature. I spent a few hours on a single answer today. Would have preferred to write it over a few sessions, but I knew if I just saved it in Notepad (Word, G Docs, w/e) I would have forgotten about it.